# calling a page method with jquery not responding on server?

Tags: jquery, .net, asp.net

I am calling a aspx page method with jquery on aspx page to check if id and email is not already registered. It was working fine on localhost but as I deployed it on hosting server  it stopped working.

I have placed alerts in javascript code and come to know either page method is not being called or a reply is not being returned from page method because alert on success or failure functions never appears. Probably it is some path or permission issue.

My page url is like **http://site.com/site1/Profile2.aspx**

and in jquery code I am giving path as `var url="Profile2.aspx/checkIDPwd"; can page's being complied change page name  ?` plz guide and help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
var url="/site1/Profile2.aspx/checkIDPwd";
```

Comment: still not working. is there any thing else that I can try or any way to debugging in this situation.

Comment: Take a look in firebug if anything is being sent. If something pops up you can debug the problem from there. If nothing pops up then you have a problem in the javascript and in that case we'd need to see some code.